# Swift function Generic

Tags: generics, swift, polymorphism

I user swift function to return class A or A's subClass like

```
func test(tst: Int) -> A {
    if(tst == 1) {
        return A()
    }
    else {
        return B()
    }
}
```

B is subClass of A

when it return B. I use dynamicType to get it's type. it will return type A.
How can I get real type.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can always try down casting.

Comment: @nhgrif I want call method According to function's return type. A's subClass will be add in future. and I not want modify this code down casting.

Comment: Is this a method in class A?

Comment: @nhgrif no, the method only in subClass and different each subClass